# updated data not loading in datatable only showing after doing F5 in ajax jquery mvc form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, asp.net-ajax

I have a `cshtml` page where I have datatable to display the data and a bootstrap pop up form via which I am doing insert and update operation. When the page loads, the data is displayed in datatable and if the user inserts new data, it is displayed after the successful insert operation.

I have having problem with UPDATE operation, after successful UPDATE operation also, the updated data is not shown in datatable. The data is displayed only after I do manual refresh of the page.
It is working for INSERT operation, the new data is shown after INSERT operation.

My cshtml code::

```
@model models.FirmModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OldRegistration";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary title_header" data-toggle="modal" onclick="modalclick()" data-target="#insert_firm_modal">Reg</a>
</p>

@*============ modal for data insert ==================*@
<div class="modal fade" id="insert_firm_modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xlg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" id="insert_firm_modal_content">
            <form id="form_firm_data" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
               // my form ........               
                <div class="modal-footer">
                   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btn_submit" />
                   <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btn_edit" style="display:none;" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@*===========================================================*@
@*======== data table data ==============*@
<div id="i_data_table">
    <table id="tblFirmData" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap title_header cell-border main_" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;">
        <thead class="table-success">
            <tr>
                <th>Edit</th>
                // other data ....
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Firm)
            {
                int status = item.FirmRegistrationStatus;
                int id = item.FirmId;
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="return getbyID(@id)">EDIT</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@*===========================================================*@
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#tblFirmData').DataTable({
        "rowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
            if (data[1] == "1") {
                $('td', row).css('background-color', '#D9EDF7');
            }
            else {
                $('td', row).css('background-color', '#A52A2A');
            }
        }
    });
    // =========== insert method ======================
    $('#btn_submit').click(function () {
        alert("submit button called...");
            // insert operation block
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/FirmModels/OldRegistration",
                data: testModel, 
                contentType: false, 
                processData: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#insert_firm_modal').modal('hide');
                    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove(); 
                    $('#form_firm_data').trigger("reset");
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                    console.log('Error - ' + errorMessage);
                }
            })

            return false;
        });
    // =========== edit method ======================
    $('#btn_edit').click(function () {
        // update operation block
        testModel.append("firmModel_", JSON.stringify(firmModel_));        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/FirmModels/Update_OldRegistration_Firm",
            data: testModel, 
            contentType: false, 
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#insert_firm_modal').modal('hide');
                $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                $('#form_firm_data').reset();
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
    // =========== get method for UPDATE ======================
    function getbyID(EmpID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/FirmModels/GetByKey",
            data: { id: EmpID },
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                // data mapping for update operation

                $('#insert_firm_modal').modal('show');
                $('#btn_edit').show();
                $('#btn_submit').hide();
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

My controller method,

```
public ActionResult OldRegistration()
        {
            var firm_data = new FirmModel();
            var firm_ = (from z in db.FirmModels where z.Status == 10 select z).OrderByDescending(z => z.FirmId).ToList();
            ViewBag.Firm = firm_;
            return View(firm_data);
        }
        
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult OldRegistration(string firmModel_)
        {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    FirmModel fm_ = new FirmModel();
                    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FirmModel>(firmModel_);
                    // insert code block

                    db.FirmModels.Add(fm_);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Your message successfuly sent!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Error..." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Update_OldRegistration_Firm(string firmModel_)
        {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    FirmModel fm_ = new FirmModel();
                    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FirmModel>(firmModel_);
                    // update code block
                    db.Entry(fm_).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Your message successfuly sent!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "error..." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

When the page loads `OldRegistration()` `GET` method is called and the `ViewBag` data populates the data table in view page, and for insert operation, new data is also populated in data table but when I do edit operation, even though the operation is successful the updated data is not showing in the datatable. I put alert code in `$('#btn_edit').click(function()` at `ajax success block`, the alert is shown but the data is not updated. The updated data is only displaying after I press F5, why is it so?

Comment: I think you have to call "OldRegistration" Get method once you are done with the edit/ update in the JS, once data is updated successfully.

Comment: @AvanthaSiriwardana How to call that? `public ActionResult OldRegistration()` and also it is not returning `json data` it is returning `view`.

Comment: I found something in here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178007/mvc3-redirect-to-action-after-ajax-call] Please have a look if it is a good fit for you